# How can i use LightStatusBar on Android M with a custom action bar?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-statusbar

While designing the User Interface, I wanted to use the black statusbar icons mode that's available for Android M and above (`Material.LightStatusBar`), but there's a problem.

I have created a main activity with 3 full screen `Fragments` using `ViewPager`, and I'm using an improvised `ActionBar` (based on relative layout with a white background, and a `TextView` as the title, so when I scroll the pager and change the fragments the `ActionBar` scrolls too) and I want to change the status bar into dark icons so it looks better on a white background. 
I tried to change my app's style into `Material.LightStatusBar`, but I don't want to use the standard `actionbar`/`toolbar` since it can't be scrolled with my `Viewpager`.

Does anybody knows how can I achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean a Toolbar can't be scrolled with a ViewPager?  One of the benefits of the Toolbar is it's versatile enough to be used like a regular View.

Comment: @DeeV thanks for replying, i haven't really known that the toolbar can be scrolled like a view,  but i am actually improvising a toolbar over a list and i have made it a little transparent so i can see the list scrolling behind, like iOS but without the blur.